# Change Touch Sound on Samsung Devices

Tags: root-access, samsung, audio, samsung-galaxy-s7, touch

This sounds silly, but it has been driving me mad for years.  I do not want to disable the touch sound, I want to change it.  This is not an option in the sound settings.  You can only disable the touch sound.

I have tried rooting my devices with no luck, and I can't find any up-to-date information about rooting either device (S7 Edge on Verizon, and Note Pro 12.2 (SM-P905V).  Every guide I've come across seems to have been copied and pasted from the same source, and it involves using Odin, but fails every time I attempt it.

There simply *must* be some way to change this sound!  The Samsung sounds are horrible 'nature inspired' crap, but I like having interface sounds.  I've wasted far too may hours trying to figure this out a couple of times a year.

Can someone confirm that it is currently NOT POSSIBLE to root the above devices?  My understanding is that Samsung aggressively patches to make rooting dificult or impossible, but I'm hoping I'm wrong.

Thankyou.

Comment: Your fault if you want to tinker and bought Verizon devices... It's not Samsung but big V who enforced the lockdown.

Comment: Ok.  I wasn't aware of that, so thanks for the additional information.  What is Verizon afraid of?  It isn't like you can get free service with a rooted device... Or maybe it's because they charge for tethering (*Sakes fist*).

Comment: Yes, tethering. You see how Verizon often uses their own tethering/hotspot implementation to enforce more strict checks... Anyway at this point I think the fight is lost. You can probably wait for root to come out for S7E (many users and relatively new), but P905V certainly isn't gonna get anything new.

Comment: Cool.  Well, now I have yet another reason to move away from Verizon once I start to feel like my devices are ready to be replaced.  Not sure that I'd get another tablet though.  I'd rather have a Surface running Windows, which I can set up however the hell I want.  I'd mark your comment as the answer if I could.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll move it to answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the sound files are placed in `/system/media/audio` which is out of reach without root. One reason why this is done is to prevent killing camera noise in regions where camera noise is required by the law.

Not being able to root the phone is purely Verizon's fault - they enforced locked bootloaders on almost all their devices. Furthermore, one can probably wait for root to come out for S7E (many users and relatively new - still has some hope), but P905V being a 3-year-old device certainly isn't gonna get anything new in the near future.